# NPM uninstall global not working

Tags: uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall my global version of webpack with NPM. I do the 
`npm uninstall -g webpack`
 but when i type 
`npm ls -g --depth=0`
 it still shows up. I tried to sudo the uninstall and now it says "Unmet peer dependency" before weback when i list global instals. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue by running `sudo` before uninstalling webpack and webpack-cli. Webpack was still being required by webpack-cli so that's why it wasn't showing up as removed until i removed them both.